# TSQL + MDX using OPENQUERY() - column names do not exist

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssas, mdx

I have a view against a OPENQUERY() which gets data from a SSAS cube.
MDX query looks like this:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Measure1] AS 
      (--calculation)
SELECT
    {[Measures].[Measure1]}
ON 0,
    NON EMPTY ([Dim1].[Dim_key].[Dim_key], [Dim2].[Dim_key].[Dim_key])
ON 1
FROM [Cube]
WHERE ([Dim3].[Hierarchy].[Level].[Member])
```

My problem is that when the WHERE filter results in 0 rows the view does not work, with error:

```
Invalid column name '[Dim1].[Dim_key].[Dim_key].[MEMBER_CAPTION]'.
```

Since its using the column name to have a GROUP BY

How can I force it return at least one row? Or always return the column names?
I cannot remove the NON EMPTY since whole set takes about 1 min to load.

So far I've tried these solutions:

[MDX - Always return at least one row even if no data is available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24903673/mdx-always-return-at-least-one-row-even-if-no-data-is-available)

[Force mdx query to return column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940995/force-mdx-query-to-return-column-names)

but it seems like it does not work since I have a where condition on another dimension.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to figure it out. Added this measure which essentially replicates Dim1 members returned on the rows:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Measure1] AS 
        (--calculation)
     MEMBER [Measures].[Dim_Key] AS
        [Dim1].[Dim_key].CurrentMember.Member_Key
SELECT
    {[Measures].[Measure1]
     ,[Measures].[Dim_Key]}
ON 0,
    NON EMPTY ([Dim1].[Dim_key].[Dim_key], [Dim2].[Dim_key].[Dim_key])
ON 1
FROM [Cube]
WHERE ([Dim3].[Hierarchy].[Level].[Member])
```

So even if there are no rows I get the new measure back as one of the columns. If there are rows I get two additional columns (which have row tags) but I just don't use them in the view